# How to request for gzipped pages from web servers through ruby scripts?

Tags: ruby, http, compression, gzip

I have a ruby script that goes and saves web pages from various sites, how do i make sure that it checks if the server can send gzipped files and saves them if available...
any help would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can send custom headers as hashes ...

```
custom_request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path, {"Accept-Encoding" => "gzip"})
```

you can then check the response by defining a response object as :

```
response = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port).start do |http| 
http.request(custom_request) 
end 

p [response['Content-Encoding']
```

Thanks to those who responded...

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the following header with your request:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

However, I am still reading how to code ruby and dont know how to do the header syntax in the net/http library (which I assume you are using to make the request)

Edit:
Actually, according to the [ruby doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Net/HTTP.src/M003948.html) it appears the this header is part of the default header sent if you dont specify other 'accept-encoding' headers.

Then again, like I said in my original answer, I am still just reading the subject so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For grabbing web pages and doing stuff with them, [ScrubyIt](http://scrubyt.org/) is terrific.